# Let $A$ be a square matrix and let $L$ be a square matrix of rank $n$ that is symmetric and positive definite on the subspace $M=({x:Ax=0})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix of rank $m$ and let $L$ be a square matrix of rank $n$ that is symmetric and positive definite on the subspace $M=({x:Ax=0})$. Show that matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}L & A^T \\A & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ is non-singular.

I tried to use the definition of non-singular matrix and get the determinant, but it's kind of unnecessary step. 
The textbook says that since $L$ is positive definite on given subspace, then this matrix is nonsingular.

Could anyone clarify this statement please?

Comment: If $A = 0$ then your matrix is singular. Is there any restriction on the dimensions of $A,L$, the rank $m$ or any other information?

Comment: @levap, $L$ is  a Lagrangiam matrix